# Integrating Google Sign-In into Android App

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client

I am following https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating guide to integrate google Sign-in into my android app.

I am working on a project where Its not possible for me to put configuration file into app folder of android project. I want to know is there any alternative for that. Can I put **API key** in the **AndroidManifest.xml** as a **meta-data** tag under application tag instead of putting google-services.json in app directory as allowed with Google map API (reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_the_api_key_to_your_application) ?

I also want to know where the configuration file (google-services.json) is used in android app because its not present in generated apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for putting meta-data tag containing API key for Google plus sign in Android api. Just need to take care that correct SHA-1 key is put in credentials.

There is no need to put configuration file for using Google plus android api. Its not used by android app at all.